# How to capture statistics on how many times a user visited a site

Tags: mysql

```
visited     200 days, 1 consecutive
```

How to capture statistics on how many times a user visited a site and how many days in a consecutive fashion much similar to what Stackoverflow provides in the profile.

Will the following table suffice?

```
create table visit_stats (id, user_id, date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure that's enough.

You could get the amount of user visits via:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visit_stats WHERE user_id=?
```

And the consecutive days have to be solved with a subselect, by checking the distance from one visit to another.

Comment: How do you do the subselect?

Comment: What did you try so far? I'm glad to help, but don't want to do your work ;)

Comment: The above code seems to work fine, but I am unable or don't know how to get the subselect working.